# I want to add custom add to cart link

Tags: php, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to add custom add to cart link. I am getting product details from product slug. And  trying to add, ADD to cart link by product id but no luck so far. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
if(!empty($tracks[ $k ][ 'buy_link_a' ])){
            list($hash, $slug) = explode("product/",$tracks[ $k ][ 'buy_link_a' ]);
            $product_obj = get_page_by_path( $slug, OBJECT, 'product' ); // this code help me to get product detials by slug
           $id=$product_obj->ID; // and here I am getting product id 
           do_action( 'woocommerce_' . $product->product_type . '_add_to_cart'  );
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `get_page_by_path()` returns a `WP_Post` object, not a `WC_Product` object. You need a `WC_Product` object, because that's the object that contains the `product_type` property. You can get a `WC_Product` from a `WP_Post` via the `wc_get_product()` function:

```
$post_obj = get_page_by_path( $slug, OBJECT, 'product' ); // this code help me to get product detials by slug
$product_obj = wc_get_product( $page_obj );
```

Your code still won't work though, because the `woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart` hook relies on the global `$product` variable, which won't be set to the product you're querying here. You could set it yourself but I'm not sure of the side effects of that. The safest way in my view would be to use the `[add_to_cart]` shortcode:

```
if(!empty($tracks[ $k ][ 'buy_link_a' ])){
    list($hash, $slug) = explode("product/",$tracks[ $k ][ 'buy_link_a' ]);
    $post_obj = get_page_by_path( $slug, OBJECT, 'product' ); // this code help me to get product detials by slug
    $product_obj = wc_get_product( $page_obj );
    echo do_shortcode( '[add_to_cart id="' . $product_obj->get_id() . '" show_price="false"]' );
}
```

If you just want the URL, use the `[add_to_cart_url]` shortcode:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[add_to_cart_url id="' . $product_obj->get_id() . '"]' );
```

Also note that I used the `get_type()` method instead of the `product_type` property, since that property has been deprecated in favour of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Please find your answer below

```
if(!empty($tracks[ $k ][ 'buy_link_a' ])){
            list($hash, $slug) = explode("product/",$tracks[ $k ][ 'buy_link_a' ]);
            $product_obj = get_page_by_path( $slug, OBJECT, 'product' ); // this code help me to get product detials by slug
           $id=$product_obj->ID; // and here I am getting product id 

       }
<a href="<?php get_bloginfo('url');?>/home-testing/?add-to-cart=<?php $product_obj->ID;?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</a>
```